# nodejs mocha how to deal with approximate matching

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

I am using mocha for testing in nodejs.

The problem is I don't know how to deal with matching nth decimal point precision. For example the following code

```
value.should.equal((0.8+0.4+1/3)/3)
```

fails with error message

```
 AssertionError: expected 0.5111111111111111 to equal 0.5111111111111112
      + expected - actual

      -0.5111111111111111
      +0.5111111111111112
```

But this is the same stuff for me. How to deal with this precision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the chai assertion library and [closeTo()](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#closeTo) assertion

```
value.should.be.closeTo(expected, delta)
```